# Can I compare (CMP) immediate values in Assembly?

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm

I tried to assemble the following instruction:

```
cmp 5, 6
```

But I got the following error:

```
invalid combination of opcode and operands
```

So I edited the previous instruction into this:

```
cmp DWORD 5, DWORD 6
```

But still I got the same error, so is comparing immediate values illegal in Assembly?

Comment: There's no reason to do that anyway. You already know the answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In x86 assembly according to your assembler(e.g *tasm, masm or nasm*) you cannot compare immediates or variables with each other. You have to put one or both of them in a register. like this:

```
mov ax, 5
cmp ax, 6
```

or

```
mov ax, 5
mov bx, 6
cmp ax, bx
```

There you go.

Comment: Yes, `CMP imm,imm` is not valid combination → http://x86.renejeschke.de/html/file_module_x86_id_35.html

Answer (score 0):

No, this is not possible. The x86 instruction set doesn't have opcodes for such operations on immediate values and assembly compilers aren't here to interpret them.

Answer (score 0):

You can compare a single immediate value with a register or with a value in memory.